# How can i make Jquery replace() pick all instances of a word in a statement and replace it once

Tags: javascript

I noticed that  Javascript inbuilt replace function cannot replace more that one particular character at a go.

I have a String say `var word = "sony sony sony is good"`

but when i want to replace all sony with apple.

```
var res = word .replace("sony", "apple");
```

I notice it doesnt replace all sony, rather it replaces them one after the other.

How can I make javascript , change all instance of a string to another at once ?

Comment: Use a global regex

Comment: @Li357 code example please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to replace all occurrences of a string in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144783/how-to-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use the [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) with regex with the `g` (for [global parameter](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_g.asp)) to replace all:

```js
var sentence = "sony sony sony is good"
console.log(sentence.replace(/sony/g, 'apple'))
```